# Print first N characters of a string (C)

Tags: arrays, c, string

My objective is to print out the first N characters (the **len** variable) of a string using a simple for loop. However, the code doesn't seem to work. e.g. with the input `printFrstChars("Example",3)` the code should print out `Exa`, but it does not print out **anything**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void printFrstChars (char inp[], int len)
{
    for(int i = 0; inp[i] != '\0' && i <= len; i++){
        printf("%s", inp[i]);

    }

}

int main ()
{   
    int len = 0;
    char inp[100];
    printf("Input string and length:\n");
    scanf("%99s %d", &inp, &len);
    printFrstChars(inp, len);
   

    return 0;
}
```

I went over the code multiple times and I (obviously) did not find the mistake that causes this. I would guess that it is either a mistake subtle enough to hide from my beginner eye, or the whole approach is wrong.

Comment: `%s` expects a pointer to a null-terminated byte string, but you are passing a single `char` with `inp[i]`

Comment: @UnholySheep Ohh, right. A rookie mistake, just as I thought. Thank you very much.

Comment: You also should have `i < len` instead of `i <= len`.

Comment: The simpler solution is `printf("%.*s", len, inp);`. But you should know how to write out the loop, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void printFrstChars (char inp[], int len)
{
    for(int i = 0; inp[i] != '\0' && i < len; i++){
        printf("%c", inp[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main ()
{   
    int len = 0;
    char inp[100];
    printf("Input string:\n");
    scanf("%99s", inp);
    printf("Input length (99 or less):\n");
    scanf("%d", &len);
    printFrstChars(inp, len);
   

    return 0;
}
```

Separating inputs, scanning into `inp` instead of `&inp`, printing each char with `%c` format, and iterating while `i < len` instead (printing a new line after). My 2 cents.

---

### Edit

Thanks to @AndrewHenle for pointing out the overflow. The `%99s` format specifier only reads max 99 chars (and the prompt states that too).

Comment: `scanf("%s", inp);` is a buffer overflow waiting to happen.  That's no better than `gets()`.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to remove the `99` from `%99s` where you are taking the string as an input. Just `%s` will work in the case, you are not entering a string with 'spaces'. Also,  In case you want to print the N number of characters, you need to put `len<N` or `len<=N-1`. Just, put `inp` instead of `&inp`.